# Wizard form in React TypeScript react-final-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

I would like to create a 3 steps form using react-final-form with TypeScript in React.js. I took pattern from [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/final-form/react-final-form/tree/master/examples/wizard?from-embed=&file=/Wizard.js:223-266), but I have problem with const static Page. I don't know how to rewrite it to TypeScript and honestly I don't know understand how it works...

So far I got this:

Wizard.tsx

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-final-form";

type Wizard = {
  onSubmit: (values: Values) => void;
};

type Values = {
  name: String;
  surname: String;
  email: String;
  password: String;
  city: String;
  birthDay: Number;
  birthMonth: Number;
  birthYear: Number;
};

// 3-steps form
const Wizard: React.FC<Wizard> = ({ onSubmit, children }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [values, setValues] = useState<Values | undefined>(undefined);
  const activePage = React.Children.toArray(children)[page];
  const isLastPage = page === React.Children.count(children) - 1;

  const static Page = (children) => children;

  // next page
  const next = (values: Values) => {
    setPage(Math.min(page + 1, React.Children.count(children)));
    setValues(values);
  };

  // previous page
  const previous = () => {
    setPage(Math.max(page - 1, 0));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (values: Values) => {
    const isLastPage = page === React.Children.count(children) - 1;
    if (isLastPage) {
      return onSubmit(values);
    } else {
      next(values);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {({ handleSubmit, submitting, values }) => {
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {activePage}
          <div className="buttons">
            {page > 0 && (
              <button type="button" onClick={previous}>
                « Powrót
              </button>
            )}
            {!isLastPage && <button type="submit">Dalej »</button>}
            {isLastPage && (
              <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                Zakończ
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        </form>;
      }}
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Wizard;
```

Register.tsx

```
    import React from "react";
import Wizard from "./wizard";

import styles from "./register.module.scss";

const Register: React.FC = () => {
  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log("onSubmit");
  };

  return (
    <Wizard onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Wizard.Page>Page 1</Wizard.Page>
      <Wizard.Page>Page 2</Wizard.Page>
      <Wizard.Page>Page 3</Wizard.Page>
    </Wizard>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Errors
on static:
`const static: any Variable 'static' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7005)`

on Page:
`const Page: (children: any) => any ',' expected.ts(1005)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull `Page` out as a separate `FC`. There's no good reason for it to be `<Wizard.Page>` instead of `<WizardPage>`.

You *could* maintain how it is by having `Wizard` be an `interface WizardWithPage extends React.FC` etc etc. But that's a waste of effort, just pull `Page` outside of `Wizard.

Comment: Do you mean `export const WizardPage: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return children;
};` above `const Wizard =[...]` ?

Comment: If you do, but I this error on WizardPage, which I don't know how to handle.. 
`Type '({ children }: { children?: ReactNode; }) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'`

Comment: Ok, I fiexed it this way: `export const WizardPage: React.FC = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
`